# What type of data structure is this assert statement testing for?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, assert

I cannot get the following assert statement to work:

```
assert(data[5] == {
    'tone': ['line', 'five', 'Test', 'one', '.'],
    'ttwo': ['line', 'five', 'Test', 'two', '.'], 
    'tline': [3]
})
```

My understanding is that it is testing for that the data indexed at position 5 in each of the lists ("tone", "ttwo", and "tline"), but is "data" meant to be a dictionary? It has curly brackets, however, if it is a dictionary that would make "tone", "ttwo", and "tline" keys, not lists, which doesn't make sense to me.

Alternatively, is `data` meant to be a list containing further lists (`tone`, `ttwo`, and `tline`) which themselves contain further lists of strings or numbers?

I think I have the data itself in the right format for `tone`, `ttwo` and `tline` (see below); I just can't figure out how to put them into "data" to make this assert statement work.

```
tone = ['line', 'five', 'Test', 'one', '.']
ttwo = ['line', 'five', 'Test', 'two', '.']
tline = 3
```

I've tried to solve this every way I know how (setting `data` as a list/tuple/dictionary) and I've had no luck. I have looked, but I can't find a similar question with the same type of data structures or assert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is a bit off.  This `assert` checks that the 6th element of `data` is a directory with those values.  The assignment to data to pass this statement might look like this:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    {
     'tone': tone,
     'ttwo': ttwo,
     'tline': tline}]
```

Now the assertion passes.

Comment: When you say that the 6th element of  of `data` is a directory, could you clarify what this could be?

To clarify things on my end, suppose `tone` and `ttwo` are already two lists containing lists of strings, as above, and `tline` is a list containing lists of numbers, but there are over a thousand related lists in each one. I have to get these all into `data` in such a way that the assert statement will find the 6th element in all three lists, without changing the element which is in that position in any of them.

Comment: No need to clarify the above, I solved it by writing a function to create dictionaries each containing the same three keys, `tone`, `ttwo` and `tline`, with values of each varying, being supplied by the elements of the three lists of the same names. Then each dictionary is appended to the list, `data`. This allows the assert statement to run as hoped.

Answer (score 3):

If `data[5]` is anything, then `data` is probably a list (or some other sequence, like a tuple, or even a dict or other mapping that happens to take integers as keys—but at any rate, you can *give* it a list, and this code will accept it).

Meanwhile, if `data[5]` is being compared to a dict with `==`, it's almost certainly supposed to be a dict. So, `data` is not just any list, but a list whose 5th element is a dict. We have no idea what the first 5 elements (or any elements beyond 5) may be, but since the assert isn't checking them, we can put anything we want there.

As for the members of that `data[5]` dict—well, you almost got them right. They are all lists—two lists of strings, and one list of ints—but notice that you wrote `tline = 3`. A list of one int is not the same value as that int; you need the list.

So, let's build it inside-out:

```
tone = ['line', 'five', 'Test', 'one', '.']
ttwo = ['line', 'five', 'Test', 'two', '.']
tline = [3]
data5 = {'tone': tone, 'ttwo': ttwo, 'tline': tline}
data = [data5 for _ in range(6)]
```

And now, it'll pass.

Answer (score 1):

`data[5]` is a dictionary with keys `"tone"`, `"ttwo"`, and `"tline"`. The value associated with each key is a list.

`data` itself could be a list or dictionary—or any other data structure that accepts integer keys (`data[5]` does not unambiguously indicate that `data` must be any particular type)—but it is *probably* a list.

You could write a `data` that would pass the test as:

```
data = [None, None, None, None, None,
        {'tone': ['line', 'five', 'Test', 'one', '.'],
         'ttwo': ['line', 'five', 'Test', 'two', '.'], 
         'tline': [3]}]
```